# vuejs disabled nav and sidebar

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-router

I know I should not put the navpart and sidepart in app.vue
now I made a login page, when in login page, the nav part and side part is hidden.
I write a v-if directive in the two tags.
When in login page, the two parts is hidden. But after login, the two parts are still hidden. I don't know where is the problem?

router:

```
{
  path: '/components/login',
  name: 'login',
  component: login
},
{
  path: '/components/userlist',
  name: 'userlist',
  component: userlist
},
```

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- <headpart class="headpart" ></headpart>
    <sidebar class="side" ></sidebar> -->

    <headpart class="headpart" v-if="['login'].indexOf($router.name) > -1"></headpart>
    <sidebar class="side" v-if="['login'].indexOf($router.name) > -1"></sidebar>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: $router.name should be $route.name

```
<headpart class="headdart" v-if="['login'].indexOf($router.name) > -1"></headpart>
```

Also, for what it's worth, I think this works too:

```
<headpart class="headpart" v-if="$route.name != 'login' "></headpart>
```